# Rvest/Stringr: Remove invisible symbols splitting words?

Tags: r, regex, rvest, stringr

I am detecting words with `stringr` and `regex` and noticed that I am missing several items because the words are split when there’s a linebreak.

Strikingly, the symbol breaking the word is not visible when I  print the cell’s content or look at it in RStudio’s data viewer. I can only see that words were split when copying-pasting the content of e.g. the dataframe’s cell into the console. There is a little dot separating the word, e.g. Schallenberg is represented as Schallen[dot]berg (a little dot, vertically in the middle of the line);

[image]

I assume that the invisibility of the symbols splitting the words has something to do with the text’s origin. They were retrieved via `rvest`. However, even more strikingly when I check the words which contain the symbol on the website, they are not split.

My question: How can I remove these otherwise invisible symbols? They are not removed with `stringr::str_squish.` Do I have to account for them when already extracting the text from the website? Many thanks!

```r
library(rvest, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyverse, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)

web_link <- "https://www.parlament.gv.at//PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00006/fnameorig_797359.html"

df_txt <- web_link %>% 
  read_html(., encoding = "latin1") %>% 
  html_nodes("body > div.WordSection37 > p:nth-child(2) > b:nth-child(2) > span") %>%
  html_text2() %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL,
          value="text_raw") %>% 
  mutate(text_raw=text_raw %>% str_squish %>% str_trim(., "both")) 

# There is a dot between Schallen - berg, but it's not visible
print(df_txt$text_raw)
#> [1] "Bundesminister für Europa, Integration und Äußeres Mag. Alexander Schallen­berg, LL.M."

str_detect(df_txt$text_raw, "Schallenberg") #false
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I assume you have to update to rvest 1.0.

Comment: Ok, this is a soft hyphen, `\xAD`. It belongs to a Control char "Other, format" Unicode category. So, you may use `gsub("\\p{Cf}+", "", df_txt$text_raw, perl=TRUE)`, or try with `stringr::str_replace_all(df_txt$text_raw, "\\p{Cf}+", "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This character you got in the input is a [*soft hyphen*](https://unicode-table.com/en/00AD/), `\xAD`. It belongs to a `Other, format` Unicode control char category. So, you can use

```r
gsub("\\p{Cf}+", "", df_txt$text_raw, perl=TRUE)
```

Or, with `stringr`:

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(df_txt$text_raw, "\\p{Cf}+")
stringr::str_replace_all(df_txt$text_raw, "\\p{Cf}+", "")
```

**NOTE**: This won't remove all invisible chars. You might want to remove any control chars other than common line break chars, `\r` and `\n`. In this case, you'd rather use

```r
gsub("[^\\P{C}\r\n]+", "", "a\n\r\\b", perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_remove_all(df_txt$text_raw, "[^\\P{C}\r\n]+")
stringr::str_replace_all(df_txt$text_raw, "[^\\P{C}\r\n]+", "")
```

where `[^\\P{C}\r\n]+` is a negated character class that matches any char but a non-control char, CR and LF chars (that is, it matches any  control char but `\r` and `\n` chars).